# List of tuples to text file

Tags: python, string, list, format, numbers

I have a List consists of String and Number like this:

`mylist= [('AGT', 3), ('GTT', 2), ('TTC', 2), ('GTA', 1), ('TAC', 1), ('ACG', 1)]`

and want to print to an output file like this

```
#output.txt
AGT,3
GTT,2
TTC,2
GTA,1
TAC,1
....
```

I have tried this code

```
     with open('output.txt', 'w+') as file:
             file.write('\n'.join(map(str, mylist))) #the join function convert the list to string
     return kFreq
```

and here is the output:

```
('AGT', 3)
('GTT', 2)
('TTC', 2)
('GTA', 1)
('TAC', 1)
('ACG', 1)
```

how do I get rid of the ( and '    ' character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate over the tuples and `join` them into strings. Also you'll need to cast all items to `str` for that:

```
print(*(','.join(map(str,i)) for i in mylist), sep='\n')

AGT,3
GTT,2
TTC,2
GTA,1
TAC,1
ACG,1
```

---

If you want it into a file:

```
with open("output.txt", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write('\n'.join([','.join(map(str,i)) for i in mylist]))
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like task for so-called [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). I would do it following way:

```
mylist= [('AGT', 3), ('GTT', 2), ('TTC', 2), ('GTA', 1), ('TAC', 1), ('ACG', 1)]
output = '\n'.join(f"{x},{y}" for x,y in mylist)
print(output)  # print to stdout for demonstration purposes
```

Output:

```
AGT,3
GTT,2
TTC,2
GTA,1
TAC,1
ACG,1
```

Be warned that this requires `Python 3.6` or newer, if you are limited to older version you might use older ways for example `.format`:

```
output = '\n'.join("{},{}".format(x,y) for x,y in mylist)
```

Regardless of your choice, `output` is ready to be written to file, that is:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w+') as file:
    file.write(output)
```